# Thunderbolt 3 dock disconnects when MacBook sleeps

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, dock, thunderbolt

I'm using a [CalDigit TS3 Thunder Station 3](http://www.caldigit.com/thunderbolt-3-dock/thunderbolt-station-3/) dock. When my MacBook sleeps, and I try to wake it using the attached USB keyboard, the DisplayPort connected screen comes on, but the dock looses connection to the USB keyboard, all other USB peripherals. Also, I have a Sonnet Echo Express III-D connected to the Thunderbolt through port on the dock and it also gets disconnected.

The ports won't come back unless I disconnect the dock and reconnect it or restart the computer.

I have contacted CalDigit support and they said:

> The “put hard disks to sleep when possible” energy saver option
>   basically sends a “dead” signal to the TS3 when it sleeps as a poor
>   attempt to save battery (despite the TS3’s charging abilities). Since
>   the computer has manually initiated a shutoff, the TS3 is unable to
>   reconnect without a manual reboot- namely, your unplugging and
>   re-plugging of the cord.
>
> At the present, we do not know of any plans on Apple’s part to update
>   their Energy Saver preferences to reflect the fact that our dock is an
>   approved charging source.

This did not solve the problem. Anytime the MacBook sleeps, the TB3 dock stops working and I have to reboot.

Assuming CalDigit is correct in stating there is nothing they can do to cure this behavior, has anyone else been able to find a work-around for this or other TB3 docks?

At present, I assume my only "fix" is to never allow my MacBook to sleep. However, there doesn't appear to be a way to prevent macOS High Sierra from sleeping. Even with utilities like Amphetamine, the computer still sleeps but is woken immediately by the utility, causing the dock to disconnect.

Comment: I've noticed similar issues with an Elgato TB3 dock which has a DP and USB-C monitor connected. (2x the same monitor LG Ultra HD 27")

I've been able to get everything to work again once I remove the TB3 cable going to my MBP for ten seconds and then plugging it back in. So far, this is more troublesome than I had hoped for in my 'single-cable' solution.

My issue usually occurs when trying to 'wake' from sleep rather than when the system goes to sleep.

Comment: I also have this issue with the Elgato TB3 dock. It is a pain having the monitor disappear. I wonder if this is some sort of problem with the Mac though, as it seems to happen with multiple different vendors docks..

Comment: What kind of monitor are you connecting to? I have an older Apple Thunderbolt Display, which is a great monitor, but unfortunately Apple isn't supporting it very well, which is why we are all using these dock solutions. Perhaps the problem is the monitor if we are all using similar ones.

Comment: Exactly the same issue: MacBookPro16,2 with Asus PA34VC for a strange reason it didn't happen that frequently with my previous MacBookPro15,2

Answer (score 7):

Given that the computer sleep seems to be the problem, I turned off the "Power Nap", and it seems to be working for me now.

- System Preferences > Energy Saver
- Power Adapter tab
- **Uncheck** "Enable Power Nap while plugged into a power adapter

This seems to be preventing the computer from sleeping and my external monitor has been fine. Note that I still turn off the display after 10 minutes, so I don't think this is harmful to the computer.

Of course, this setup is only when plugged in, which is the only time I care about the external monitor.

Comment: THANK YOU JIM!  Turning off "Power Nap" worked for me (MacBook Pro 2019 16" on Catalina 10.15.4, connected to CalDigit TS3+ Hub w/ USB midi keyboard).  For the record, it has been several days now and NO SLEEP CRASHES.  Prior to applying your solution, MBP would crash EVERY TIME I closed the lid for more than an hour or two.  Note: For several days I unplugged the Hub (the only wired connection to MBP) whenever closing the MBP lid, and it didn't crash once.  So I'm confident that it's the Power Nap.  Apple Tech had suggested a complete OS reinstall, whew!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and am getting the same response from CalDigit Support.  I'm on macOS High Sierra, MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports).

Some apps will prevent your computer from sleeping, such as Amazon Music.  I find that if I leave that running, the computer doesn't sleep and this problem is avoided.  Preventing the computer from sleeping is definitely not a real solution though... :-(